# Pegar o total de registros de um JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Eu preciso fazer uma comparação com o valor total de registros que existem no banco de dados, em determinada tabela. Eu poderia obter esse valor via PHP, e passar para o JavaScript, durante a renderização da página, porem, os registros podem ser adicionados/excluídos dinamicamente, e, então, o total de registros pode ser alterado. Na verdade, o que me interessa e fazer uma comparação com o total de valores exibidos (ou que podem ser exibidos, no caso de paginação), pois para o usuário, a tabela reflete o banco.

Não acho uma boa solução criar uma Action no controler, só para responder uma requisição por esse valor, já que "teoricamente" eu tenho ele disponível.

A configuração do datatable:

```
    $("#datagrid").DataTable({
        oLanguage: DT_PTBR,
        dom: 'l<"toolbar-h"fT>rtip',
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/datatable-data",
```

Como o carregamento é dinâmico, a solução de contar linhas do tabela, não funciona.

Eu pesquisei por uma soluções, e encontrei sugestões para obter o valor que eu quero dessa forma:

> oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal()

No caso, não dava pistas de como o `oTable` poderia ser obtido. Então pesquisei por uma forma de obter este "objeto", e aparentemente ele é obtido dessa forma:

```
var oTable = $("#datagrid").DataTable({
```

Mas ao utilizar tal objeto, na solução acima, ocorre um erro ("fnSettings", não é uma função).
Tentei dessa forma também:

```
 $("#datagrid").DataTable().fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal()
```

e

```
  $("#datagrid").DataTable().fnRecordsTotal()
```

Mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score -2):

utilize

```
$("#datagrid").dataTable().fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal()
```